# jQuery, how do I find the max width of an object array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, this is what I thought would work:

```
Math.max($j.map($j.makeArray($j(".rl_shell")), function(val, i){
    $j(val).width();
}));
```

breakdown:

```
$j.isArray($j.makeArray($j(".rl_shell")))
```

returns true

and when I do just

```
$j.map($j.makeArray($j(".rl_shell")), function(val, i){
        $j(val).width();
    })
```

I get an empty array (`[]`) as a result.

```
$j(".rl_shell")
```

returns [div, div]

so, I'm guessing, that I'm using map wrong, but I used the syntax here: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ so I'm not exactly sure what the deal is.

EDIT:

as per a couple of the answer's suggestions, I've come up with this:

```
$j.map($j.makeArray($j(".rl_shell")), function(val, i){
    return $j(val).width();
});
```

which returns `[0,950]`

but when I add Math.max around it, I get `NaN` =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you wanting to get the widest of all selected elements?

```
Math.max.apply(Math, $('selector').map(function(){ 
    return $(this).width(); 
}).get());
```

Comment: I've come across an issue, I've updated my question to reflect the new problem.

Comment: why add the .get() at the end?

Comment: `.get` converts jQuery object collection into native array. You have to provide an array to the `.apply`. So `Math.max([0,950])` returns `NaN` while `Math.max.apply(Math, [0, 950])` is equivalent to `Math.max(0, 950)` and returns `950`.

Answer (score 2):

You just forget `return` from `map` callback:

```
Math.max($j.map($j.makeArray($j(".rl_shell")), function(val, i){
    return $j(val).width();
}));
```

Comment: bah, too used to ruby not requiring return o.o

Comment: I've come across an issue, I've updated my question to reflect the new problem.

Answer (score 2):

Besides you missed the `return` of the `map` callback,

You should use `Math.max.apply(window, arr)` to get the max value of an array.

Pass an array directly to `Math.max` will return `NaN`.

The code will be like below:

```
Math.max.apply(window, $.map($('.rl_shell'), function() {return $(this).width();}));
```

Comment: oh hey, that's exactly what I just ran into. =D